# How to print json data in SliverList, i am getting an error "the getter length was called on null"

Tags: json, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have worked a little on a flutter json tutorial, where I am able to fetch and parse json data, I am now trying to put the code into a SliverList. But when I debug my app it throws the follwing error on `Builder` on line 96: `The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length`

I am not sure what to do or what to change. Please note that my app consists of 1 Page with tabbar view.

Here is my full code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:innbo_app/product_model.dart';

Future<List> fetchData(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tariksalihovic/innbo/receipt');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseData, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List parseData(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map((json) => Receipt.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class PlaceholderWidget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  PlaceholderWidget1(this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}

class Indbo1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final List data;

  Indbo1({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> listItems = [];
  final List<String> _tabs = <String>[
    "Alle",
    "Anmeldt",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.grey[100],
          child: DefaultTabController(
            length: _tabs.length, // This is the number of tabs.
            child: NestedScrollView(
              headerSliverBuilder:
                  (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                // These are the slivers that show up in the "outer" scroll view.
                return <Widget>[
                  SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                        context),
                    sliver: SliverSafeArea(
                      top: false,
                      sliver: SliverAppBar(
                        centerTitle: true,
                        title: const Text(
                          "Indbo",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                        floating: true,
                        pinned: true,
                        snap: true,
                        stretch: false,
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          // These are the widgets to put in each tab in the tab bar.
                          tabs: _tabs
                              .map((String name) => Tab(text: name))
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              body: TabBarView(
                // These are the contents of the tab views, below the tabs.
                children: _tabs.map((String name) {
                  return SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    bottom: false,
                    child: Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return CustomScrollView(
                          key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
                          slivers: <Widget>[
                            SliverOverlapInjector(
                              // This is the flip side of the SliverOverlapAbsorber above.
                              handle: NestedScrollView
                                  .sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                            ),
                            SliverPadding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 10),
                              sliver: SliverList(
                                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                                  Text(
                                    'Genstande',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SliverList(
                              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                [
                                  Container(
                                    child: FutureBuilder<List>(
                                      future: fetchData(http.Client()),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.hasError)
                                          print(snapshot.error);

                                        return snapshot.hasData
                                            ? Indbo1(data: snapshot.data)
                                            : Center(
                                                child:
                                                    CircularProgressIndicator());
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            width: 1.0,
                                            color: Colors.grey[200]),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    margin:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            width: 1.0,
                                            color: Colors.grey[200]),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    margin:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: data.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return ListTile(
                                          /*onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                      Detail(choice: choices[index])),
                      );
                      },*/
                                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 26,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
                                            child: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          title: Text(
                                            '${data[index].receiptlines[index].name ?? "Empty"}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: 16.5,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                          ),
                                          subtitle: Text(
                                            '${data[index].orderNumber ?? "Empty"}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.grey[700],
                                                fontSize: 12.0),
                                          ),
                                          trailing: Text(
                                            '${data[index].price.amount ?? "Empty"}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: 16.5,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the product_model.dart which is linked to above code:

```
class Lines {
  final String name;
  final String productNumber;

  Lines({this.name, this.productNumber});

  factory Lines.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Lines(name: json['name'], productNumber: json['productNumber']);
  }
}

class Prices {
  final int amount;

  Prices({this.amount});

  factory Prices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Prices(
      amount: json['amount'],
    );
  }
}

class Receipt {
  final int id;
  final String type;
  final String receiptId;
  final String orderNumber;
  final Prices price;
  final List<Lines> receiptlines;

  Receipt(
      {this.id,
        this.type,
        this.receiptId,
        this.orderNumber,
        this.price,
        this.receiptlines});

  factory Receipt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['receiptLines'] as List;
    List<Lines> receiptLines =
    List<Lines>.from(list.map((i) => Lines.fromJson(i))).toList();

    return Receipt(
        id: json['id'],
        type: json['type'],
        receiptId: json['receiptId'],
        orderNumber: json['orderNumber'],
        price: Prices.fromJson(json['price']),
        receiptlines: receiptLines
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you seemed to have a `product_model`, please add that to you code too. It seems there are other codes or files related to it you did not post here.

Comment: itemCount: data.length Did you fetch the data?

Comment: @RatnadeepChakraborty I have added the product_model.dart code now.

Comment: As @AfridiKayal mentioned. At `line 160` inside your `ListView.builder` it seems that `data` is null, it does not have anything. Check it.